Why are all the gradient parameters in the model None?
This is my model.
My plan is to make a model that fuses camera and radar images.
class FusionNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, radar_channels=1, camera_channels=3, n_classes=2, bilinear=False):
        super(FusionNet, self).__init__()
        self.radar_channels = radar_channels
        self.camera_channels = camera_channels
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.bilinear = bilinear
        factor = 2 if bilinear else 1

        # Encoder for radar images
        self.enc0_radar = DoubleConv(radar_channels, radar_channels)
        self.enc1_radar = Encoder(radar_channels, 8 // factor)
        self.enc2_radar = Encoder(8, 16 // factor)
        self.enc3_radar = Encoder(16, 32 // factor)

        # Encoder for camera images
        self.enc0_camera = DoubleConv(camera_channels, camera_channels)
        self.enc1_camera = Encoder(camera_channels, 8 // factor)
        self.enc2_camera = Encoder(8, 16 // factor)
        self.enc3_camera = Encoder(16, 32 // factor)

        # Fusion
        self.fusion0 = Fusion()

        # Decoder
        self.dec1 = Decoder(32, 16 // factor, bilinear)
        self.fusion1 = Fusion()
        self.dec2 = Decoder(48, 8 // factor, bilinear)
        self.fusion2 = Fusion()
        self.dec3 = Decoder(24, n_classes, bilinear)
        self.outc = OutConv(n_classes, n_classes)

    def forward(self, radar_img, camera_img):
        
        print(f"radar: {radar_img.size()},camera: {camera_img.size()}")
        # Radar image encoding
        x0_radar = self.enc0_radar(radar_img) #
        x1_radar = self.enc1_radar(x0_radar)  # 1->8 channel    (1,210,70)->(8,105,35)
        x2_radar = self.enc2_radar(x1_radar)  # 8->16 channel   (8,105,35)->(16,52,17)
        x3_radar = self.enc3_radar(x2_radar)  # 16->32 channel  (16,52,17)->(32,26,8)

        # Camera image encoding
        x0_camera = self.enc0_camera(camera_img)  #
        x1_camera = self.enc1_camera(x0_camera)  # 3->8 channel   (3,210,70)->(8,105,35)
        x2_camera = self.enc2_camera(x1_camera)  # 8->16 channel  (8,105,35)->(16,52,17)
        x3_camera = self.enc3_camera(x2_camera)  # 16->32 channel (16,52,17)->(32,26,8)

        # Fusion
        # x3_fusion = self.fusion0(x3_radar, x3_camera)
        x3_fusion  = x3_radar + x3_camera

        # Decoding 1
        upsample = UpsampleWithExactSize((52, 17))
        x2_dec = upsample(self.dec1(x3_fusion))           # 
        x2_fusion = self.fusion1(x2_radar, x2_camera, x2_dec)
        
        # Decoding 2
        upsample = UpsampleWithExactSize((105, 35))
        x1_dec = upsample(self.dec2(x2_fusion))
        x1_fusion = self.fusion2(x1_radar, x1_camera, x1_dec)

        # Decoding 3
        upsample = UpsampleWithExactSize((210, 70))
        x0_dec = upsample(self.dec3(x1_fusion))

        # Ofefwut
        ogm = self.outc(x0_dec)  # Final output
        return ogm

class DoubleConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, mid_channels=None):
        super().__init__()

        if not mid_channels:
            mid_channels = out_channels

        self.double_conv = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels, mid_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(mid_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(mid_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.double_conv(x)


class Fusion(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def forward(self, x0_rad, x0_cam, x0=None):
        if x0 is not None:
            x = torch.cat([x0_rad, x0_cam, x0], dim=1)
        else:
            x = torch.cat([x0_rad, x0_cam], dim=1)

        return x


""" Downscaling w/ maxpool & double conv. """
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super().__init__()
        self.maxpool_conv = nn.Sequential(nn.MaxPool2d(2), DoubleConv(in_channels, out_channels))
       
    def forward(self, x):
        return self.maxpool_conv(x)


""" Upscaling & double conv. """
class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, bilinear=True):
        super().__init__()

        # if bilinear, use the normal convolutions to reduce the number of channels
        if bilinear:
            self.up = nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2, mode="bilinear", align_corners=True)
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels // 2, out_channels, in_channels // 2)   
        else:
            self.up = nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels, in_channels // 2, kernel_size=2, stride=2) 
            self.conv = DoubleConv(in_channels // 2, out_channels)                               

    def forward(self, x0):
        x = self.up(x0)
        return self.conv(x)


class OutConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels):
        super(OutConv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=1)
       
    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.conv(x)
        return x1


class DownsampleConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=2, stride=2, padding=0):
        super(DownsampleConv, self).__init__()
        self.conv = nn.Conv2d(in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding=padding)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.conv(x)


class UpsampleWithExactSize(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_size):
        super(UpsampleWithExactSize, self).__init__()
        self.output_size = output_size

    def forward(self, x):
        # Up-sample to the exact size
        x_up = F.interpolate(x, size=self.output_size, mode="bilinear", align_corners=True) 
        return x_up

I already did it with required_grad=true. But I don't know why this error occurs.
It is strange...
Gradient for parameter enc0_radar.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_radar.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_radar.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_radar.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_radar.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_radar.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_radar.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_camera.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_camera.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_camera.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_camera.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_camera.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc0_camera.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc1_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc2_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter enc3_camera.maxpool_conv.1.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.up.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.up.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.conv.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.conv.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.conv.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.conv.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.conv.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec1.conv.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.up.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.up.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.conv.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.conv.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.conv.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.conv.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.conv.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec2.conv.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.up.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.up.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.conv.double_conv.0.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.conv.double_conv.1.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.conv.double_conv.1.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.conv.double_conv.3.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.conv.double_conv.4.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter dec3.conv.double_conv.4.bias is None.
Gradient for parameter outc.conv.weight is None.
Gradient for parameter outc.conv.bias is None.

Yeah, train.py works, but the score is weird.
and the training results are weird, too
What should I do? Please help me.
what does it mean the gradient for parameter is None?
This is train.py code.
import argparse
import logging
import os
import random
import sys
from pathlib import Path

import numpy
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.transforms.functional as TF
from torch import optim
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, random_split,TensorDataset
from tqdm import tqdm
from PIL import Image
import wandb
from evaluate import evaluate
from radOGM import FusionNet, radOGM
from utils.data_loading import BasicDataset, CarvanaDataset
from utils.dice_score import dice_loss

dir_radar = Path("./data/radar/")
dir_camera = Path("./data/camera/")
dir_mask = Path("./data/masks/")
dir_checkpoint = Path("./checkpoints/")


def train_model(
    model,
    device,
    epochs: int = 5,
    batch_size: int = 1,
    learning_rate: float = 1e-5,
    val_percent: float = 0.1,
    save_checkpoint: bool = True,
    img_scale: float = 1.0,
    amp: bool = False,
    weight_decay: float = 1e-8,
    momentum: float = 0.999,
    gradient_clipping: float = 1.0,
):

    # 수정사항: dataset 3개: radar, camera, mask===================================
    # 1. Create dataset
    try:
        dataset = CarvanaDataset(dir_radar, dir_camera, dir_mask, img_scale)
    except (AssertionError, RuntimeError) as e:
        print(f"Error creating FusionDataset: {e}")
        return
    # ============================================================================

    # 2. Split into train / validation partitions
    n_val = int(len(dataset) * val_percent)
    n_train = len(dataset) - n_val
    train_set, val_set = random_split(dataset, [n_train, n_val], generator=torch.Generator().manual_seed(0))

    # 3. Create data loaders
    loader_args = dict(batch_size=batch_size, num_workers=os.cpu_count(), pin_memory=True)
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_set, shuffle=True, **loader_args)
    val_loader = DataLoader(val_set, shuffle=False, drop_last=True, **loader_args)

    # (Initialize logging)
    experiment = wandb.init(project="U-Net", resume="allow", anonymous="must")
    experiment.config.update(
        dict(
            epochs=epochs,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            learning_rate=learning_rate,
            val_percent=val_percent,
            save_checkpoint=save_checkpoint,
            img_scale=img_scale,
            amp=amp,
        )
    )

    logging.info(
        f"""Starting training:
        Epochs:          {epochs}
        Batch size:      {batch_size}
        Learning rate:   {learning_rate}
        Training size:   {n_train}
        Validation size: {n_val}
        Checkpoints:     {save_checkpoint}
        Device:          {device.type}
        Images scaling:  {img_scale}
        Mixed Precision: {amp}
    """
    )

    # 4. Set up the optimizer, the loss, the learning rate scheduler and the loss scaling for AMP
    optimizer = optim.RMSprop(
        model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate, weight_decay=weight_decay, momentum=momentum, foreach=True
    )
    scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.ReduceLROnPlateau(optimizer, "max", patience=5)  # goal: maximize Dice score
    grad_scaler = torch.cuda.amp.GradScaler(enabled=amp)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() if model.n_classes > 1 else nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    global_step = 0

    # 5. Begin training
    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        model.train()
        epoch_loss = 0
        with tqdm(total=n_train, desc=f"Epoch {epoch}/{epochs}", unit="img") as pbar:
            for batch in train_loader:
                # =================================================================================
                radar_images, camera_images = batch["radar"], batch["camera"]
                true_masks = batch["mask"]
                # =================================================================================

                assert radar_images.shape[1] == model_instance.radar_channels, (
                    f"Network has been defined with {model_instance.radar_channels} input channels, "
                    f"but loaded images have {radar_images.shape[1]} channels. Please check that "
                    "the images are loaded correctly."
                )

               

                # =================================================================================
                radar_images = radar_images.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float32, memory_format=torch.channels_last)
                camera_images = camera_images.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float32, memory_format=torch.channels_last)
                true_masks = true_masks.to(device=device, dtype=torch.long)

                # radar_images = torch.tensor(radar_images,requires_grad=True)
                # camera_images = torch.tensor(camera_images,requires_grad=True)
                # true_masks = torch.tensor(true_masks,requires_grad=True)
                # =================================================================================

                print(f"Radar image shape: {radar_images.size()}")
                print(f"Camera image shape: {camera_images.size()}")
                print(f"Mask image shape: {true_masks.size()}")

                # torch.autograd.set_detect_anomaly(True)
                with torch.autocast(device.type if device.type != "mps" else "cpu", enabled=amp):
                    # =================================================================================
                    masks_pred = model(radar_images, camera_images)
                 
                    print(f"Model output shape: {masks_pred.size()}")  
                    check_gradients(model)
                    # =================================================================================
                    if model.n_classes == 1:
                        loss = criterion(masks_pred.squeeze(1), true_masks.float())
                        loss += dice_loss(F.sigmoid(masks_pred.squeeze(1)), true_masks.float(), multiclass=False)
                    else:
                        loss = criterion(masks_pred, true_masks)
                        loss += dice_loss(
                            F.softmax(masks_pred, dim=1).float(),
                            F.one_hot(true_masks, model.n_classes).permute(0, 3, 1, 2).float(),
                            multiclass=True,
                        )

                optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)
                grad_scaler.scale(loss).backward()
                torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), gradient_clipping)
                grad_scaler.step(optimizer)
                grad_scaler.update()

                pbar.update(radar_images.shape[0])
                global_step += 1
                epoch_loss += loss.item()
                experiment.log({"train loss": loss.item(), "step": global_step, "epoch": epoch})
                pbar.set_postfix(**{"loss (batch)": loss.item()})

                # Evaluation round
                division_step = n_train // (5 * batch_size)
                if division_step > 0:
                    if global_step % division_step == 0:
                        histograms = {}
                        for tag, value in model.named_parameters():
                            tag = tag.replace("/", ".")

                            if not torch.isinf(value).any():
                                histograms["Weights/" + tag] = wandb.Histogram(value.data.cpu())
                            if not torch.isinf(value.grad).any():
                                histograms["Gradients/" + tag] = wandb.Histogram(value.grad.data.cpu())
                       
                        val_score = evaluate(model, val_loader, device, amp)
                        scheduler.step(val_score)

                        logging.info("Validation Dice score: {}".format(val_score))
                        try:
                            experiment.log(
                                {
                                    "learning rate": optimizer.param_groups[0]["lr"],
                                    "validation Dice": val_score,
                                    "images": wandb.Image(radar_images[0].cpu()),
                                    "masks": {
                                        "true": wandb.Image(true_masks[0].float().cpu()),
                                        "pred": wandb.Image(masks_pred.argmax(dim=1)[0].float().cpu()),
                                    },
                                    "step": global_step,
                                    "epoch": epoch,
                                    **histograms,
                                }
                            )
                        except:
                            pass

        if save_checkpoint:
            Path(dir_checkpoint).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
            state_dict = model.state_dict()
            state_dict["mask_values"] = dataset.mask_values
            torch.save(state_dict, str(dir_checkpoint / "checkpoint_epoch{}.pth".format(epoch)))
            logging.info(f"Checkpoint {epoch} saved!")


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Train the UNet on images and target masks")
    parser.add_argument("--epochs", "-e", metavar="E", type=int, default=5, help="Number of epochs")
    parser.add_argument("--batch-size", "-b", dest="batch_size", metavar="B", type=int, default=4, help="Batch size")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--learning-rate", "-l", metavar="LR", type=float, default=1e-4, help="Learning rate", dest="lr"
    )
    parser.add_argument("--load", "-f", type=str, default=False, help="Load model from a .pth file")
    parser.add_argument("--scale", "-s", type=float, default=1.0, help="Downscaling factor of the images")
    parser.add_argument(
        "--validation",
        "-v",
        dest="val",
        type=float,
        default=10.0,
        help="Percent of the data that is used as validation (0-100)",
    )
    parser.add_argument("--amp", action="store_true", default=False, help="Use mixed precision")
    parser.add_argument("--bilinear", action="store_true", default=False, help="Use bilinear upsampling")
    parser.add_argument("--classes", "-c", type=int, default=2, help="Number of classes")

    return parser.parse_args()


def check_gradients(model):
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        # if param.grad is not None:
        #     print(f"Grad for {name}: {param.grad}")
        if param.grad is None:
            print(f"Gradient for parameter {name} is None.")
        elif torch.isinf(param.grad).any():
            print(f"Gradient for parameter {name} contains inf values.")
        elif torch.isnan(param.grad).any():
            print(f"Gradient for parameter {name} contains NaN values.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_args()

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(levelname)s: %(message)s")
    device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
    logging.info(f"Using device {device}")

    # Change here to adapt to your data
    # n_channels=3 for RGB images
    # n_classes is the number of probabilities you want to get per pixel
    # model = UNet(n_channels=3, n_classes=args.classes, bilinear=args.bilinear)

    # ==================================================================================================
    model = FusionNet(radar_channels=1, camera_channels=3, n_classes=args.classes, bilinear=args.bilinear)
    # ==================================================================================================
    if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:  # for multi-GPU
        model = torch.nn.DataParallel(model)

    # model = model.to(memory_format=torch.channels_last)
    # Access model attributes correctly depending on whether DataParallel is used
    model_instance = model.module if isinstance(model, torch.nn.DataParallel) else model
    logging.info(
        f"Network:\n"
        f"\t{model_instance.radar_channels + model_instance.camera_channels} input channels\n"
        f"\t{model_instance.n_classes} output channels (classes)\n"
        f'\t{"Bilinear" if model_instance.bilinear else "Transposed conv"} upscaling'
    )

    if args.load:
        state_dict = torch.load(args.load, map_location=device)
        del state_dict["mask_values"]
        model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
        logging.info(f"Model loaded from {args.load}")

    model.to(device=device)
    try:
        train_model(
            model=model,
            epochs=args.epochs,
            batch_size=args.batch_size,
            learning_rate=args.lr,
            device=device,
            img_scale=args.scale,
            val_percent=args.val / 100,
            amp=args.amp,
        )
    except torch.cuda.OutOfMemoryError:
        logging.error(
            "Detected OutOfMemoryError! "
            "Enabling checkpointing to reduce memory usage, but this slows down training. "
            "Consider enabling AMP (--amp) for fast and memory efficient training"
        )
        torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        model.use_checkpointing()
        train_model(
            model=model,
            epochs=args.epochs,
            batch_size=args.batch_size,
            learning_rate=args.lr,
            device=device,
            img_scale=args.scale,
            val_percent=args.val / 100,
            amp=args.amp,
        )



Maybe this could be because of the instruction here?
optimizer.zero_grad(set_to_none=True)? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.optim.Optimizer.zero_grad.html
Which is why you are getting None gradients?
